# Submit Button Animation

Tags: html

My website includes a submit button that is working, however it is not animation (this is what it should look like:  codepen.io/seansean11/pen/wHIae)

The animation worked fine until I made it a submit button.  My question is, how can I delay the page from loading the next page until the button animation plays?

http://milescwatson.com/asb_test/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the on submit event and then play the animation. After the animation is done then you call submit

Answer (score 0):

The only way possible I see is jquery `submit()`: [see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

By submiting you call a function that would handle the animation before loading other page.

By the way, why would you need to animate button if it for loading other page? Will it show error if something goes wrong? Otherwise I don't see a point of it. You can simply show success message after loading, that more helpful and informative to user.